# csv file format for uploading large amount of data in mysql db using php

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I have two types of csv file.For one type of csv, the data is uploading fine but not for another one.I am little bit confused if this is happening because of the csv file or it's a problem in the sql.

Type 1 (Which works fine)

```
"user.id as" (column name)
"1"
"2"
```

Type 2 (Which doesn't work)

```
user.id as (column name)
1
2
```

My sql is

```
$insert_query = "LOAD DATA local INFILE '".$target_path."'
                INTO table master_huts
                FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                IGNORE 1 LINES
                (hutids)";
```

Any suggestion/hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces in column names is asking for problems if you are asking me ;)
Quote the column name.. as you should for every string.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't have any space in column name.Also the files are being generated by third party as csv file but I am quite sure this is not exact csv file.

Comment: So the only actual difference between the files is the integers beeing quoted?

Comment: Yes that's the only difference. With quotes worked but not without quotes.